# How to expose Jupyter cells based on R language as REST API via Jupyter Kernel Gateway?

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-kernel-gateway

In Jupyter notebook I created a R cell that has the R following code:

```
#GET /r/test

data <- read.csv("/home/jovyan/work/data/heart-failure.csv")

# Split the data into training and test sets. (0.75, 0.25) split.
sampled <- sample(1:nrow(data), 0.75 * nrow(data))
train <- data[sampled, ]
test <- data[-sampled, ]
print(train,quote = TRUE, row.names = FALSE)
```

In order to expose the cell as REST API, I have annotated the cell with the Jupyter Kernel Gateway annotation

```
#GET /r/test
```

When I started a docker container that enables the usage of Jupyter Kernel Gateway, I got the error

```
RuntimeError: No endpoints were discovered. Check your notebook to make sure your cells are annotated correctly.
```

Does Jupyter Kernel Gateway support R language based cells to be exposed as REST API? If yes, how can I achieve this functionality?

Comment: Try `# GET` instead of `#GET`

Comment: Thank you @danlooo. It worked. Please add your comment as solution for my problem. I'll mark it as solved as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://jupyter-kernel-gateway.readthedocs.io/en/latest/http-mode.html#getting-the-request-data), there is always a space between `#` and `GET`, so you need to write `# GET /r/test` instead:

```
# GET /r/test

data <- read.csv("/home/jovyan/work/data/heart-failure.csv")

# Split the data into training and test sets. (0.75, 0.25) split.
sampled <- sample(1:nrow(data), 0.75 * nrow(data))
train <- data[sampled, ]
test <- data[-sampled, ]
print(train,quote = TRUE, row.names = FALSE)
```